# Bounded linear operators that commute with translation

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to read Elias Stein's "Singular Integrals" book, and in the beginning of the second chapter, he states two results classifying bounded linear operators that commute (on $L^1$ and $L^2$ respectively).

The first one reads:

Let $T: L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a bounded linear transformation. Then $T$ commutes with translations if and only if there exists a measure $\mu$ in the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity), s.t. $T(f) = f \ast \mu$ for every $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is also true that $\|T\|=\|\mu\|$.

The second one says:

Let $T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be bounded and linear. Then $T$ commutes with translation if and only if there exists a bounded measurable function $m(y)$ so that $(T\hat{f})(y) = m(y) \hat{f}(y)$ for all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is also true that $\|T\|=\|m\|_\infty$.

I was wondering if anyone had a reference to a proof of these two results or could explain why they are true.

Comment: Here is a hint for the first part. Let $\phi_\epsilon(x)=\phi(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon^n$ where $$\phi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}e^{|x|^2/(|x|^2-1)}&\text{if }|x|<1\\0&\text{if }|x|\ge1\end{array}\right.$$ $\|T\phi_\epsilon\|_{L^1}$ is bounded as $\epsilon\to0$, so there is a sequence $\{\epsilon_k\}$ and a measure $\mu$ so that $T\phi_{\epsilon_k}\to\mu$ weakly in $L^1$.

Comment: @robjohn: it may be worth pointing out that the only thing you need is that you have an approximate unit in in the convolution algebra $L^1$ consisting of continuous functions of compact support. Making it explicit doesn't help much, I think. But it's a great hint!

Comment: @Theo: Yes, you are right. There is nothing special about the $\phi$ I gave, other than it is positive, has compact support, and is in $L^1$. Originally, I started out writing up a proof using this $\phi$, but due to time constraints, I posted a hint instead.  When I get time later, I may finish the proof.

Comment: Great book. For a reference check out Grafakos' "Classical Fourier Analysis". (It is not quite what you want but it is a similar result).

Comment: For the second one the definition should be $(Tf)^\wedge=m\hat{f}$ (otherwise $T$ is just multiplication by $m$ rather than a Fourier multiplier operator).

Answer (score 9):

For the first one:

Let $\phi_\epsilon(x)=\phi(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon^n$ where
$$
\phi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}c\;e^{|x|^2/(|x|^2-1)}&\text{if }|x|<1\\0&\text{if }|x|\ge1\end{array}\right.
$$
and $c$ is chosen so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=1$.

$\|T\phi_\epsilon\|_{L^1}$ is bounded as $\epsilon\to0$, so there is a sequence $\{\epsilon_k\}$ and a measure $\mu$ so that $T\phi_{\epsilon_k}\to\mu$ weakly in $L^1$.

Since $T$ is continuous, linear, and commutes with translation,
$$
\begin{align}
f*\mu(x)
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\;\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\;T\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\;\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\;T(\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y))\;\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\;\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}T(f(y)\;\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y))\;\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\;T\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\;\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)\\
&=T\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\;\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\;\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)\\
&=Tf(x)
\end{align}
$$
For the second one the definition should be $(Tf)^\wedge=m\hat{f}$ (otherwise $T$ is just multiplication by $m$ rather than a Fourier multiplier operator). Let $\psi(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ so that $\hat{\psi}=\psi$.
$$
\begin{align}
\psi(\xi)\;(Tf)^\wedge(\xi)
&=(\psi*Tf)^\wedge(\xi)\\
&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\psi(x-y)\;Tf(y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)^\wedge(\xi)\\
&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\psi(y)\;Tf(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)^\wedge(\xi)\\
&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}T^{\;*}\psi(y)\;f(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)^\wedge(\xi)\\
&=(T^{\;*}\psi)^\wedge(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)
\end{align}
$$
Let $m(\xi)=(T^{\;*}\psi)^\wedge(\xi)/\psi(\xi)$, then we have
$$
(Tf)^\wedge(\xi)=m(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)
$$
and therefore, $\|m\|_{L^\infty}=\|T\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: I have two simple questions here: 1. Isn't the argument rather that you have a sequence $\phi_{\epsilon_k}$ that converges weak$^{\ast}$ in $(C_0)^{\ast}$ and do your computation for $f$ continuous with compact support first and then extend the equality $f \ast \mu = Tf$ for $f \in C_c$ to all of $L^1$ by continuity of both sides? 2. You say "so there is a sequence ... and a measure $\mu$ such that $\phi_{\epsilon_k} \to \mu$ weakly in $L^1$". What result do you have in mind here? I've never seen such a statement and re-proved variants by hand as needed. Could you give me a reference, please?

Comment: @robjohn: I was going to ask the same question as Theo. Also, how do you go from $\int f(y) T(\phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y)) dy = \int T(f(y)) \phi_{\epsilon_k}(x-y) dy$? Wouldnt it be $T^*$?

Comment: @Theo: $L^1$ is a subset of the signed Radon measures, $\mathcal{M}$, which is the dual of $C_c$. $\mathcal{M}$ is weakly-* compact in that any bounded sequence $\{\mu_k\}$ in $\mathcal{M}$ contains a subsequence which converges weakly-* to some $\mu\in\mathcal{M}$ (that is when tested against any $f\in C_c$). One reference is [Weak and weak star convergences](http://jpmandallena.pagesperso-orange.fr/weak-convergence.pdf).

Comment: @user1736: your parentheses do not match mine. I am simply using the linearity and translation invariance of $T$ (that is, $T$ is operating on $x$, and $y$ is just translation that can be moved outside $T$).

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for the reference, but you're essentially saying the same as I did in my comment. However, you want to take the dual of $C_0$ (functions vanishing at infinity) not of $C_c$ (functions of compact support--which you usually don't equip with the sup-norm but with a different topology). By the way, Theorem 7.1 in the linked notes is wrong in that the space $C_c$ is *not* complete wrt the sup-norm. I do object to your usage of "converges weakly in $L^1$", then (which would involve duality with $L^\infty$). But it's merely a technical detail and I'm happy with your argument.

Comment: @Theo: I had originally written $C_0$, but the reference I cited used $C_c$, so I thought that perhaps I had misremembered. Of course you are correct, and $C_c$ should be changed to $C_0$ in my last comment. My weak vs weak-* notation was a little sloppy, too.

Comment: @robjohn: Oh, I think I can see what you mean. So you're also just using linearity to pull $T$ outside of the integral, and to pull the limit inside then, right?

Comment: @user1736: linearity to pull $T$ outside, and continuity to pull the limit inside. Yes.

Comment: @robjohn Does your solution for part (ii) show both directions?

Comment: @user412674: my answer shows that if $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $L^2$ that commutes with translations, then $T$ is a Fourier multiplier operator with a bounded measurable function. The other direction follows pretty easily by [Plancherel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem).

Comment: $|T\varphi_{e_k}|_{L^1}\leq C|\varphi_{e_k}|_{L^1}$
now, why $\varphi_{e_k}$ is bounded in $L^1$?

Comment: Each $\varphi_{\epsilon_k}$ has the same $L^1$ norm by the dilation properties of that norm.

Comment: $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\phi(x/\epsilon)}{\epsilon^n}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: I have this: $|Tϕϵ|L1≤C|ϕϵ|L1$ because $T$ is bounded. $|Tϕϵ|L1$ is bounded when $ϵ→0$ if$ |ϕϵ|L1$ is bounded when $ϵ→0.$ Now, |ϕ_e|_{L1}=∫|x|<1ce|x/ϵ|2/(|x/ϵ|2−1)endx . Then limϵ→0 $\int_{|x|<1} \frac{ce^{{|x/\epsilon|^2}/{(|x/\epsilon|^2-1)}}dx<\infty?$ –

Comment: Please read my last two comments. All of the $\phi_{\epsilon_k}$ have **the same** $L^1$ norm; so, yes, the limit is $\lt\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I have already understood that part.
Of course, there are other parts that I still don't understand ...
Will you by chance have the reference of the star convergence that was in the link above? (the link is down)

Comment: The [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) has it at [weak-convergence.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512112622/http://jpmandallena.pagesperso-orange.fr/weak-convergence.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. 
At what step did you use that the linear transformation T is invariant under translations? I can't see where it's used.
I know that T invariant traslation if $\tau_{h}T=T\tau_{h}$ for every $\tau_{h}$ traslation.

Comment: $f(x)=\lim_{k\to \infty} \int f(y)\phi_{e_{k}}(x-y)dy$ It is a result of a theorem?

Comment: [Approximation of the Identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function)

Comment: thanks but Is there a result similar to theorem 7.12 of the link https://web.archive.org/web/20130512112622/http://jpmandallena.pagesperso-orange.fr/weak-convergence.pdf, with $C_ {0}$ instead of $C_ {cc}$?

Comment: The dual space of $C_{cc}$ is contained in dual space of $C_{0}$?
Ask this then, the statement says that there is a measure in the dual space of $C_0$. But, theorem 7.12 of the link above says that there is a measure in the space of measures of positive Radon, which is dual of $C_ {cc}$.
In this way, I want to see that given a measure $\mu\in (C_ {cc})^ {\ast})$ then $\mu \in (C_ {0})^{\ast}$ which I don't know if it's true ...
$C_{0}\subset C_{cc}$ implies $(C_{cc})^{\ast}\subset (C_{0})^{\ast}$?

Comment: Why $\left\|m\right\|_{\infty}=\left\|T\right\|_{L^2}$?

Answer (score 3):

Let me just give a literature reference, in case that's what you are interested in. The classical paper on translation invariant operators on Lebesgue spaces is Hormander's 1960 *Acta* paper "Estimates for translation invariant operators in $L^p$ spaces". If you have access to MathSciNet, [here's the mref](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=121655).

Answer (score 0):

A bounded linear operator $ T: L^2 \to L^2$ and commutes with translation

Known result from Riesz Representation theorem [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809632/proof-that-every-bounded-linear-operator-between-hilbert-spaces-has-an-adjoint):$\int Tf(s)u(s) ds=\int f(s)T^*u(s)ds$ written as $<Tf,u>=<f,T^*u>$, where $ T^*$ is the linear adjoint operator of $ T $ , $ u \in L^2$

now for $f(s)$ translated  by $x$ ,$f(s+x)$

we have $\int Tf(s+x)u(s)ds=\int f(s+x)T^*u(s)ds$

Now take Let $u_{\epsilon}=\phi_\epsilon(s)=\phi(s/\epsilon)\epsilon^{-1}$ where
$\phi(s)$ is normalized gaussian function with zero mean.

$\int Tf(s+x)u_{\epsilon}(-s) ds=\int Tf(s+x)u_{\epsilon}(s)ds=\int f(s+x)T^*u_{\epsilon}(s)ds$

$H(s)=Tf(s)$ , by translation commutation $H(s+x)=Tf(s+x)$

$R(-s)=T^*u_{\epsilon}$

we have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} H* u_{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f*R$

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} H*u_{\epsilon}=H(x)$ ae

for $u \in L^1$ function, we have the following theorem regarding fourier transform:

$v(x)=g*u=\int g(s)u(x-s) ds$
for $g \in L^2$ , define $\hat{g}=lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{n}^{-n}g(s)e^{2i\pi x z} dx$ the limit exists in the sense of $L^2$. If $u \in L^1$ and $\int |g(s)||u(x-s)| ds \le P$ where $P$ is a non negative integrable function in $L^2$ then $\hat{v}=\hat{g}\hat{u}$

Proof : $g_n=g1_{[-n,n]},v_n=g_n*u$
it's known that $\hat{v_n}=\hat{g_n}\hat{u}$
By dominated convergence theorem $lim_{n \to \infty} ||v-v_n||^2=0$
and by Plancherel theorem $lim_{n \to \infty} ||v-v_m||^2= lim_{n \to \infty} ||\hat{v}-\hat{v_n}||^2=0$
This implies $lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{v_n}=\hat{v}$

Now from our equation when $u$ is a normalized  Gaussian we have $|H|* |u_{\epsilon}| \le MH(x)$ where $MH(x)$ is the Hardy Littlewood Maximal function (also $ ||MH(x)||^2 \le ||H(x)||^2$)
using Fourier transform $\hat{H}(z)\hat{u_{\epsilon}}(z)=\hat{f}(z)G(z)$ where $G(z)=\hat{R}$

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\hat{ u_{\epsilon}}=1$

$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}G=m(z)$

consequently we have $\hat{Hf}(z)=m(z)\hat{f}(z)$