# Is the transformation $f\mapsto T(f):=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi))$ always translation-invariant?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is   the transformation $f\mapsto T(f):=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi))$ always translation-invariant?

My attempt: (with $f$ a Schwartz function)
\begin{align}
(T (\tau_hf))(x)&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi)\widehat{\tau_hf}(\xi))(x))\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{ix\xi}m(\xi)\widehat{\tau_h f}(\xi)\,d\xi\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{ix\xi}m(\xi)\mathrm{e}^{ih\xi}\widehat{f}(\xi)\,d\xi\\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(\tau_h (Tf))(x)&=\tau_h(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi))(x)\\
&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi))(x+h)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{i(x+h)\xi}m(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi)\,d\xi\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{ix\xi}m(\xi)\mathrm{e}^{ih\xi}\widehat{f}(\xi)\,d\xi
\end{align}

Therefore, $\tau_h T=T\tau_h$?, for any $m(\xi)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ Or does the function $m(\xi)$ need some additional assumptions?

Comment: this is called commute with translation. and yes, because the translation is multiplication operation.

Comment: possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354210/operator-t-commutes-with-all-translations-leftrightarrow-t-is-multiplicat?rq=1

Comment: @Yimin. But, it's sufficient that $m(\xi)$ is bounded? Where I can find a reference? thanks!

Comment: @eraldcoil deps on what space your T defined with, say Schwartz to $L^\infty$. Then it should be correct.