# Proof that every bounded linear operator between hilbert spaces has an adjoint.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

As a practice exercises(not an assignment question) for one of the papers I am doing currently at university we are asked to show the following;

I $T:H \rightarrow K$ is a bounded linear operator from between two Hilbert spaces. Show that there exists a unique bounded linear operator $T^*:K\rightarrow H$ such that

$$
\langle Th,k\rangle = \langle h,T^*k \rangle\ \ \ \ \forall h\in H,\ \ \forall k\in K.
$$

Uniqueness is easy, for if there existed $S,P \in \mathcal{L}(K,H)$ satisfying this property then we would have

$$
\langle h, Pk-Sk\rangle =0 \ \ \ \ \forall h \in H \ \ \ k\in K
$$
in particular for $Pk -Sk \in H$ we would have

$$
\langle Pk-Sk, Pk-Sk\rangle = 0 \ \ \ \forall k\in K
$$
which means $Pk= Sk$ for all $k\in K$ so they are the same.

**Proof of existence**

We start by fixing $k \in K$. Now we define the linear functional $L_k : H \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ by

$$
L_k(h) := \langle Th,k \rangle, \ \ \ \  h \in H
$$
($L_k$ is linear by linearity of $T$ and linearity of inner products and bounded by Cauchy-Schwarz.) Now by the Riesz - Representation Theorem we know there exists a unique $v \in H$ such that

$$
L_k(h) = \langle h,v \rangle , \ \ \ \ \  \forall h \in H.
$$

Notice that the $k \in K$ that we fixed was arbitrary so for each $k \in K$ there exists a unique $v_k \in H$ such that

$$
\langle Th,k\rangle = L_k(h) = \langle h,v_k \rangle , \ \ \ \ \  \forall h \in H.
$$

Now we define the function $T^* :K \rightarrow H$ where

$$
T^* (k) := v_k, \ \ \ \ k \in K.
$$

Now we claim that $T^*$ is linear and bounded.

We start by showing that $T^*$ is linear. So we fix $k,g \in K$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, the case where $k = g = 0$ is trivial so we assume $k,g \neq 0$, then we need to show that

$$
T^*(\lambda k +g) = \lambda T^*k +T^*g.
$$

Or by the uniqueness of $T^*(k)$ for all $k \in H$ it is enough to show show that

$$
\langle Th,\lambda k +g \rangle = \langle h, \lambda T^*k +T^*g \rangle, \ \ \ \ \forall h \in H
$$
Now for arbitrary $h \in H$ we have

$$
\langle Th, \lambda k +g \rangle = \bar{\lambda}\langle Th,k \rangle + \langle Th,g \rangle = \langle h, \lambda T^*k\rangle +\langle h, T^*g \rangle = \langle h, \lambda T^*k +T^*g \rangle
$$

as needed for linearity.

Now for boundedness we notice for $k \in K$, (the case where $k = 0$ is trivial so we may assume $ k \neq 0$)

$$
||T^*k||^2 = \langle T^*k,T^*k \rangle = \langle k , T(T^*k) \rangle \leq ||k||\ ||T(T^*k) || \leq ||k||\ ||T||_{\text{op}}\ || T^*k ||
$$

By simple rearranging it follows that

$$
||T^*k|| \leq ||T||_{\text{op}}\ ||k||.
$$

As a bonus we also notice that the from infemum characterization of the operator it follows that

$$
||T^*||_{\text{op}}\leq ||T||_{\text{op}}.
$$

**QED**

Comment: Do you know the Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces? Fix $x \in H$. Use $x$ and $T$ to find a linear functional on $K$. Now note that every linear functional is of a certain kind by the Riesz representation theorem : it is given by the inner product with a certain element of $K$. The map $T^*$ should take $x$ to this element. Now show that $T^*$ is linear and bounded. (If further hint is required, I will write an answer.)

Comment: Yes, I have encountered the Riesz Representation theorem, that was another exercise. I did not know to look in its direction for this problem though. Thanks very much. I will use it to prove this then add my proof and edit my question to a proof check instead.

Comment: You are welcome! Please return for doubts.

Comment: I've added my proof, Would you be so kind as to check it?

Comment: It is correct. Well done, $+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted proof is the proof presented above.