# Operator commutes with translation and bounded measurable function. Stein.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

In [Bounded linear operators that commute with translation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61509/bounded-linear-operators-that-commute-with-translation)

It has:
 Let $m(\xi)=(T^{\;*}\psi)^\wedge(\xi)/\psi(\xi)$, then we have
$$
(Tf)^\wedge(\xi)=m(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)
$$
and therefore, $\|m\|_{L^\infty}=\|T\|_{L^2}$.

Why $\|m\|_{L^\infty}=\|T\|_{L^2}$.
I can't see this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $\|T\|_{L^{2}} \leq \|m\|_{\infty}$ is obvious from the definition of the norm.  Now let  $N$ be a positive integer and an $\epsilon >0$ and consider $I_A$ where $A=\{\xi: |m(\xi)| > \|m\|_{\infty} -\epsilon, \|x\|\leq N\}$. (We can choose $N$ such that $A$ has positive measure). This is an $L^{2}$ function and hence it can be written as $\hat {f}$ for  some $L^{2}$ function $f$. Now $\|T\|_{L^{2}} \geq \frac {\|m(\xi)\hat {f}(\xi)\|_2} {\|f(\xi)\|_2} $ by definition of the norm of $T$. Now just simplify the last expression and let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: I did not understand very well how to continue.
$\frac {\| m(\xi)\hat {f}(\xi)\|_2} {\|f(\xi)\|_2}
=\frac{\| m(\xi) m(\xi)I_{A} \|_{2}}{\| \hat{f}\|_2}
=\frac{\| m(\xi) m(\xi)I_{A} \|_2}{\| m(\xi)I_{A}\|_{2}}$

Comment: @eraldcoil My answer was wrong. I have corrected it now.

Comment: i have doubts.
$\frac{\| m(\xi) m(\xi)I_{A} \|_2}{\| m(\xi)I_{A}\|_{2}}=\frac{\int_{A}m^2(x)dx}{\int_{A} |m(x)|dx}...$

Comment: On $A$ we have $|m(\xi)| >\|m\|_{\infty} -\epsilon$. So $\int_A |m(\xi)|^{2} \geq (\|m\|_{\infty} -\epsilon)^{2} \lambda (A)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Note that $\sqrt {\lambda(A)}$ cancels when you take the ratio.

Comment: $\|T\|^2\geq$ 
$\frac{\| m(\xi) m(\xi)I_{A} \|_2^2}{\| m(\xi)I_{A}\|_{2}^2}
=\frac{ \int_{A} |m(x)|^4dx}{\int_{A}|m(x)|^2dx}
\geq \frac{(|m|_{\infty}-\epsilon)^4\lambda(A)}{|m|_{\infty}^2\lambda(A)}
=\frac{(|m|_{\infty}-\epsilon)^4}{|m|_{\infty}^2} \to |m|_{\infty}^2\\$ 

when $\epsilon\to 0$

Therefore $\|T\|\geq \|m\|_{\infty}$ !!
However,  can't see the need for $N \to \infty$

Comment: No need to let $N \to \infty$. But for the argument to be valid yo u have to make sure that you don't get $0$ in the denominator. If $N$ is large then $\lambda (A) >0$. You can fix any $N$ with this property. @eraldcoil

Comment: I have a doubt.

Why is inequality $\|T\|\leq \|m\|_{\infty} $obvious?
I have this:
$\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|_{2}\leq 1}\|T(f)\|_{2}\leq \sup_{\|f\|_{2}\leq 1} \|m\|_{2}$

Comment: @eraldcoil Recall that $f$ and $\hat f$ have the same $L^{2}$ norm.

Comment: thanks.
$\|(Tf)^{\wedge}\|_{2}=\|m\hat{f}\|_{2}\leq \|m\|_{\infty} \|\hat{f}\|_{2}$
Plancherel implies $\|T(f)\|_{2}\leq \|m\|_{\infty}\|f\|_{2}$
then $\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1} \|T(f)\|_{2}\leq \|m\|_{\infty}$
i.e. $\|T\|\leq \|m\|_{\infty}$!